# belongs_to / has_many not behaving as expected in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, one-to-many

models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first, :last, :uuid, :books
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  attr_accessor :blurb, :published, :title, :person
  attr_accessible :person
end
```

I created a `Person` using the **Rails 3.2.8 console** like this:

```
person = Person.create!( {:first => "John", :last => "Doe"} )
```

and then created a `Book`

```
book = Book.create!( {:title => "Ruby for Dummies"} )
```

I then try to associate them like this:

```
person.books << book
```

When I query the person for books, I get an array with the book I created, but when I query the book for the person it belongs to, I get nil. I expected to get the person, given that all information was persisted (I see the SQL commands and I checked the database and the data is correct, i.e. the row in the book table points back to the person id it should.)

What am I missing?

thanks

Edit- Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `persons` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `last` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `uuid` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

CREATE TABLE `books` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `blurb` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `published` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `person_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. Can you show the db schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your migrations are correct, there is nothing wrong with your code which should produce the following results:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > person = Person.create!( {:first => "John", :last => "Doe"} )
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (145.9ms)  INSERT INTO "people" ("book_id", "created_at", "email", "first", "last", "updated_at", "uuid") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["book_id", nil], ["created_at", Mon, 03 Sep 2012 21:35:53 UTC +00:00], ["email", nil], ["first", "John"], ["last", "Doe"], ["updated_at", Mon, 03 Sep 2012 21:35:53 UTC +00:00], ["uuid", nil]]
   (43.5ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Person id: 1, email: nil, first: "John", last: "Doe", uuid: nil, book_id: nil, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:35:53", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:35:53"> 
1.9.3p194 :005 > book = Book.create!( {:title => "Ruby for Dummies"} )
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("blurb", "created_at", "person_id", "published", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["blurb", nil], ["created_at", Mon, 03 Sep 2012 21:36:25 UTC +00:00], ["person_id", nil], ["published", nil], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 03 Sep 2012 21:36:25 UTC +00:00]]
   (4.4ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Book id: 1, blurb: nil, published: nil, title: nil, person_id: nil, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:36:25", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:36:25"> 
1.9.3p194 :006 > person.books << book
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "books" SET "person_id" = 1, "updated_at" = '2012-09-03 21:36:39.566387' WHERE "books"."id" = 1
   (4.4ms)  commit transaction
  Book Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."person_id" = 1
 => [#<Book id: 1, blurb: nil, published: nil, title: nil, person_id: 1, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:36:25", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:36:39">] 
1.9.3p194 :007 > Book.all
  Book Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" 
 => [#<Book id: 1, blurb: nil, published: nil, title: nil, person_id: 1, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:36:25", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:36:39">]
```

The problem is with your Book model, try the following:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :person, :title, :person

  belongs_to :person
end
```

**Before**:

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > Book.last
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Book id: 4, blurb: nil, published: nil, title: nil, person_id: 1, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:55:33", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:55:33"> 
1.9.3p194 :003 > Book.last.person
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

**After**:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > Book.last
  Book Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Book id: 4, blurb: nil, published: nil, title: nil, person_id: 1, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:55:33", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:55:33"> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > Book.last.person
  Book Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Person Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Person id: 1, email: nil, first: "John", last: "Doe", uuid: nil, created_at: "2012-09-03 21:48:02", updated_at: "2012-09-03 21:48:02">
```

Comment: I'm thinking something is wrong with the console. I see the same as you describe. have you tried querying the book for the person? > book.person

Comment: prusswan, do you create a new rails app for each question like this?

Comment: @Dan the problem is within your model definition I believe. Using your model, I get the correct `book.person_id` but not the correct `book.person`

Comment: @NoahClark I just need to modify one of the sample applications I use for bootstrapping work, not too much trouble. If you see my profile you can tell I have many of those

Comment: @prusswan cool, at least the problem is reproducible. any clue as to what's missing in my models?

Comment: @prusswan you rock! so the attr_accessor was messing with the attr_accessible ? kind of a under-the-hood overriding of the setter/getter methods ?

Comment: possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448414/why-does-attr-accessor-clobber-the-existing-variables-in-this-model-in-ruby-on-r

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like the following? If so, what does book.person give you?

```
person = Person.create!( {:first => "John", :last => "Doe"} )
book = Book.create!( {:title => "Ruby for Dummies"} )
book.person_id = person.id


person.books 
book.person
```

Comment: person.books gives me an empty array, book.person gives nil

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't set the person_id in the create action?

Comment: I wanted to create the instances isolated and associate them "manually" later. When I do it your way, the book knows the person, but the person does not know the books, i.e. person.books return []

Comment: @Dan, I think you'll still run into the same problems, but that is how I would associate them "manually" later if I were to do it.